# Export Database Table To JSon Using Apache Camel Not Behaving As Expected

Tags: json, database, apache-camel, export

I would like to export a table of a database to JSON file with this code using the code listed below, the code runs but splits returned data rows into a file per record not a single file as expected.

Camel's route :

```
 public void configure() throws Exception {
    JsonDataFormat jsonFormat = new JsonDataFormat(JsonLibrary.XStream);
    jsonFormat.setUnmarshalType(Customer.class);
    from("sql: SELECT * FROM assignment01.staff?dataSourceRef=dataSource")
            .marshal(jsonFormat)
            .to("file:data/test");
}
```

there is my xml

```
    <bean id="route" class="com.huyqtran.JSonRoute"/>
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <routeBuilder ref="route"/>
</camelContext>
<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/assignment01?useSSL=false"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
</bean>
```

I expect that the application just create one JSON file for the whole table.

Comment: And what happens? And what version of Camel are you using?

Comment: it transforms each record of the table to a file. I'm using version 2.19.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tell Camel to append to the file with option `fileExist=Append`: http://camel.apache.org/file2, eg

```
 .to("file:data/test?fileExist=Append");
```

or tell the SQL component to return the entire result-set by turning of its iterator, eg `useIterator=false`

```
   from("sql: SELECT * FROM assignment01.staff?dataSourceRef=dataSource&useIterator=false")
```